# Duplicate records were creating while inserting contact Role on Opportunity?

Tags: apex, controller, visualforce-component

I am trying to insert Contact Role on Opportunity. But with my trigger 2  same records were inserted. why and how to make it not allowing duplicate record ?

```
**trigger Opportunity_Primary on Opportunity (before insert,before update, After Update) {

   List<OpportunityContactRole> OppContactRole = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
    OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
   set<OpportunityContactRole> sid = new set<OpportunityContactRole>();
    for (Opportunity O : Trigger.new) {
        if (O.Contact_Name__c!=Null){

            ocr.OpportunityId = O.Id;
            ocr.ContactId = O.Contact_Name__c;
            ocr.IsPrimary = True;
            sid.add(ocr);  
            OppContactRole.addall(sid);      }

    }
    if(OppContactRole.size()>0)
    insert OppContactRole;
    }**
```

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
OppContactRole.addall(sid);
```

Should be added outside the loop. Putting it inside the loop add records multiple time as OppContactRole is a list not a set.

Running the same logic for multiple events (before update and after update) is not a best practice as well. It makes the logic runs twice. You should run the logic once and use conditions if you want the code to run based on particular event.

Answer (score 0):

your trigger is running on both before insert and before Update that's why two records are being inserted.Try performing the trigger operation on before insert and after update.

Comment: Thanks, This could be resolved. But every time when i am edit and save the records were created repeatedly.

Comment: Hi,
Try making different cases in the trigger for befor insert and after update conditions using (trigger.IsUpdate) and trigger.Isinsert.
update in case of after update and insert in case of before insert.

Comment: For the update i am getting error like Id is not specified

Comment: I am getting error while  creating new opportunity record. The trigger is working okay for updating old records.

Comment: can you post your updated code..?